# Problem in clicking on icon

Tags: automated-testing

I am trying to click the image icon via xPath, but when I run the code the link present on image icon is not opening. Could you please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Would you mind providing the sample html where you got the problem identifying the element?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe *your xpath is wrong*. You can use add-on FirePath for Firefox to get the xpath of the image. In order to let the link be clicked, your xpath should end with tag `a`, not `img`.

For example, suppose xpath of the image is `.//*[@id='navbar_notice_6']/p/a/img`, you should remove `/img`, then your command in java will be:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navbar_notice_6']/p/a")).click();
```